# Validate date - User should only select dates from next month

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have a datepicker field (SharePoint 2013) in custom list. I am trying to do a validation for the particular date field (DtStartDate).
Conditions are:
1) User should not select past dates from current date
2) User should be selecting dates from next month from current date. Example: if date is 4/26/2017, then user should not select any date till 5/26/2017. If they select, I want to show an error message.

I have tried the below code:

```
var dtStartDate = $("input[title='Start Date Required Field']").val();
// Get today's date
var todaysDate = new Date();
// Create date from input value
if(dtStartDate.length > 0)
{                   
inputStartDate = new Date(dtStartDate);
// call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if( (inputStartDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) || (inputStartDate < todaysDate ) ) {
// StartDate equals today's date or Date is in the Past
msg = msg + "<br/> Demand Start Date should be greater than Today's Date";
}
}
```

How to check the validation for the 2nd case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tru Adding days to your date picker

```
Datefrom.MinDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```js
var d = new Date();      // current date
var date = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);  // add month to the current date
var inputDate = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2)); // add two months to the current date
console.log('comparison date - ' + new Date(date));
console.log('input date - ' + inputDate);
if(date < inputDate.getTime())
  console.log('valid date');
else
  console.log('invalid date');
```

Comment: Hi. I tried the code. I am getting the error as "Object doesn't support property or method 'getMonth' "

Comment: can you post the tried script. to use getMonth method object should be a date object. var d = new Date(); d.getMonth()